# How can I fetch mysql single column list results directly into a list in python?

Tags: python, mysql, list, tuples

I have a mysql call:

```
zip = 48326

cursor.execute ("""
    select distinct(name) 
      from usertab 
     where zip= %s
""" , (zip))

result = cursor.fetchall()
```

The result is returned in a tuple that looks like this:

```
result = (('alan',), ('bob',), ('steve',), ('tom',))
```

But I need a list like this:

```
mylist= ['alan', 'bob', 'steve', 'tom']
```

So I process the tuple into a list like this:

```
mylist = []

for row, key in enumerate(result):
    for col, data in enumerate(key):
        mylist.append(data)
```

This code works, but I'd like a simpler way.
How can I fetch a mysql single column result directly into a list?

Comment: Thanks to Tadeck and Pawelmhm... I compacted my mysql fetch to this:   mylist = [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do it like that, using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
mylist = [row[0] for row in result]
```

It will flatten your result and create list from it.

Another approach, without list comprehension:

```py
from itertools import chain
mylist = list(chain.from_iterable(result))
```

It will flatten a result and convert it to list.

Answer (score 0):

75 % of Python question on StackOverflow can be answered with the words: "list comprehension";)

Here is a solution using list comp:

```
>>> result = (('alan',), ('bob',), ('steve',), ('tom',))
>>> mylist = [i[0] for i in result]
>>> mylist 
['alan', 'bob', 'steve', 'tom']
```

Please learn more about list comprehension [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), it will save you a good deal of time.

Comment: First ;) "_75 % of Python question on StackOverflow can be answered with the words: "list comprehension";)_" - do you have source for that?

Comment: Well ok I don't have a source :) but really there is so many questions that can be solved with list comprehension, this tool is really so powerful, and so many people are unaware of it.

Comment: Well, in fact, list comprehension is just a shortcut.